# Задача про NP и coNP

Tags: алгоритм, теория

Есть задача 3SAT: выяснить, выполнима ли данная в 3-КНФ формула.

Есть задача TAUT: выяснить, является ли данная формула тавтологией.

Требуется доказать эквивалентность следующих утверждений:

1. NP = coNP
2. [3SAT полиномиально сводится к TAUT] & [TAUT полиномиально сводится к 3SAT]

Мне удалось доказать в одну сторону (из первого следует второе), однако с доказательством в другую сторону возникли проблемы, уже на уровне идеи. Предполагать, что они (NP и coNP) не равны и приходить к противоречию не получается, а каких-то иных способов я пока не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 -> 2:

Из NP = coNP = K (обозначим этот класс буквой К) следует, что каждый язык (задача) из класса К за полиномиальное от входа время сводится к задаче из класса NPC = coNPC = KC, то есть все задачи из класса К сводятся к TAUT, так как все они принадлежат coNP (К), а также сводятся к 3SAT, так как все они принадлежат NP (К). В частности TAUT и 3SAT сводятся друг к другу.

- 2 -> 1:

3SAT полиномиально сводится к TAUT, значит каждая задача L из NP полиномиально сводится к coNPC задаче и мы можем быстро (за полином) проверить НЕпринадлежность слова к задаче L: x ∉ L <=> f(x) ∉ TAUT (полиномиально сводим задачу L к TAUT, а затем полиномиально проверяем сертификат НЕпринадлежности f(x) к языку TAUT. Из чего следует, что NP ⊆ coNP. Аналогично из [TAUT полиномиально сводится к 3SAT] получаем coNP ⊆ NP. Значит NP = coNP.